# How to speed up Imgur Image upload to API

Tags: reactjs, image, imgur

I work on a project with React.js and trying to make a form to upload some images:
[image]

But it took forever to upload all the images. So it should upload all the image  on submit.  Sometimes it works fine but sometimes seems like it never even upload a single image. If I set it to upload image on change, I afraid it will  put to many unused image in imgur storage, but if I upload everything on one go, it took forever. Can anyone give me suggestion about how to speed up images upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to speed up Imgur Image upload to API

Depends if you want to upload the original image *"no matter what"* or you are okey with **resizing** or **compressing** your image.

If you are okey with **resizing**, you could set a maximum resolution for each image, like `1280x960`, it would significantly reduce the file size, especially if images are e.g. `4K`.

If you are okey with **compressing**, you could convert the `png` images into e.g. `jpeg` using `canvas`. It would also reduce the file size.